# Jquery Show and hide

Tags: jquery

```
$('#TOTSBILT').click(function(){
    $("#Vsauceisgenius").show("slow");
    $(".arrow-left").show("slow");
});
```

Why it is not showing div I also have this code

```
$("#CTSO").click(function(){
      $("#Vsauceisgenius").hide("slow");
      $(".arrow-left").hide("slow");
```

There is no errors

```
<div  id="TOTSBILT"  ><img src="../img/lupa.png" ID="ILDSIB" class="OKSD"></div><div id="ATSIMD"><div class="arrow-left" id="JUHBG"></div><div id="Vsauceisgenius"   >
    <img src="../img/x.png" id="CTSO" href="#"><form method="post" action="ppl.php" >
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="People" id="IMOHD"><input type="submit" name="Searc" value="Search" id="DPMM">
    </form><P></P>
    <form method="get">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Hashtags" id="IMOHDS"><input type="submit" value="Search" id="DPMMM"></form>
</div>
</div><h1 ID="jcss">2</H1>
```

Comment: is your id unique?if not please make it unique.maybe is it dynamically created?if yes use event delegation

Comment: is it dynamically created?

Comment: Can you show your HTML? It would be much easier to help ;-)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w9azf8eo/2/ working fine

Comment: @Pekka i dont know why but it is not working:(

Comment: did you include the correct js? look at console if there are errors

Comment: i think somewhere with in the entire html there is an id that exist like your id i cant think of any other reason why i wont work. you've seen the fiddle it works perfectly

Comment: yes i will check now @Pekka

Comment: No its fine and by the way hide is working fine @Pekka

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: show is not working @Pekka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(function(){
$("#CTSO").click(function () {
    $("#Vsauceisgenius").hide("slow");
    $(".arrow-left").hide("slow");
});//close this click handler
$('#TOTSBILT').click(function () {
    $("#Vsauceisgenius").show("slow");
    $(".arrow-left").show("slow");
});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="TOTSBILT"  ><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Q/l/L/B/F/a/search-icon-hi.png" style="width:20px;height:20px;" ID="ILDSIB" class="OKSD"></div><div id="ATSIMD"><div class="arrow-left" id="JUHBG"></div><div id="Vsauceisgenius"   >
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/256x256/DeleteRed.png" id="CTSO" href="#" style="width:20px;height:20px;"><form method="post" action="ppl.php" >
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="People" id="IMOHD"><input type="submit" name="Searc" value="Search" id="DPMM">
    </form><P></P>
    <form method="get">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Hashtags" id="IMOHDS"><input type="submit" value="Search" id="DPMMM"></form>
</div>
</div><h1 ID="jcss">2</H1>
```

Comment: @J.doe what is not working ?,run the snippet code and check,it is working.just replace your code and try.see for any error in console.